# obtain IMDB database movie links automatically for movie list in text file?

Tags: web

I have a list of movies in a text file. I would like some way to automatically obtain the IMDB movie hyperlinks for each item in my list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Although this isn't a direct link to the IMDB for the movie, it will probably work in most cases.  Just use Google's *I'm Feeling Lucky* feature.  Of course you will need to URL encode the movie title, but something like this should work:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=imdb+%22Movie+Title%22&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky
```

Replacing `Movie+Title` with each URL encoded title of course.

Here is an Excel VBA macro you can use to do URL encoding(courtesy of [Motobit)](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/sa323.htm):

```
Function URLEncode(ByVal Data, CharSet)
  'Create a ByteArray object
  Dim ByteArray: Set ByteArray = CreateObject("ScriptUtils.ByteArray")
  If Len(CharSet)>0 Then ByteArray.CharSet = CharSet

  ByteArray.String = Data

  If ByteArray.Length > 0 Then
    Dim I, C, Out

    For I = 1 To ByteArray.Length
      'For each byte of the encoded data
      C = ByteArray(I)
      If C = 32 Then 'convert space to +
        Out = Out + "+"
      ElseIf (C < 48 Or c>126) Or (c>56 And c<=64) Then
        Out = Out + "%" + Hex(C)
      Else
        Out = Out + Chr(c)
      End If
    Next
    URLEncode = Out
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out some of the samples provided by [Dean Clatworthy](http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/).

Comment: Although, I suggest you hurry because March 1st is your deadline before IMDB's new ToS kick in.